# Jmathai-twitter-async logging only through one account

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have used jmathai-twitter-async for creating a twitter app on my website using PHP. everything is working fine except that it always login through only one account and that account is the one through which i have created the twitter app on dev.twitter.
can anyone tell me what can be the reason behind this? Is it the exception in api or am i missing something?
thanks in advance.
i thought in the begining that i have hardcoded it... but i checked whole of my code but i found nothing. here's is my code for login-twitter.php

```
<code>
   <?php
    session_start(); 
    require_once('twitterLib/EpiCurl.php');
    require_once('twitterLib/EpiOAuth.php');
    require_once('twitterLib/EpiTwitter.php');
    require_once('twitterLib/secret.php');
    require_once('config/functions.php');
    $twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $token, $secret);
    $twitterObjUnAuth = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    $oauth_token = $_GET['oauth_token'];
    if($oauth_token == '')
    { 
    $url = $twitterObjUnAuth->getAuthenticateUrl();
    header('Location:'.$url);
    }
    else{ 
    $token = $twitterObj->getAccessToken();
    $twitterObj->setToken($twitterObj->token, $twitterObj->tokenSecret);         
    $_SESSION['ot'] = $twitterObj->token;
    $_SESSION['ots'] = $twitterObj->tokenSecret;
    $twitterInfo = $twitterObj->get('/account/verify_credentials.json');
    $twitterInfo->response;
    $username = $twitterInfo->screen_name;
    $profilepic = $twitterInfo->profile_image_url;
    $uid = $twitterInfo->id;
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = "twitter";
    $user = new User();
    $userdata = $user->checkUser($uid, 'twitter', $username,'',$twitterObj->token,$twitterObj->tokenSecret,$profilepic,$ip_address);
    if(!empty($userdata)){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];           
    header('Location:index.php?id='.$_SESSION['id']);
    }
    else
    {}
    }     
    ?>
</code>
```

now the problem here is that $twitterInfo->response is always giving the same response i.e. it is always login with the account through which i have created the app. why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have hardcoded the user key and secret.

Why not show some code where you think the problem occurs.